# Searching and replacing Verilog code using Perl

Tags: regex, perl, verilog

I have some expressions in a file:

```
   e = a & b;
   f = e | c;
   d = ~f;
```

I need to resolve these expressions into a compound expression like this:

```
   d = ~ ((a & b) | c)
```

How can I do this in Perl. Are there any CPAN modules that I can use for this? Or, can this be done without using modules?

I am working on a `verilog` parser project.

Comment: you want something like #define, am i right?

Comment: Have you tried [searching CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=verilog&mode=all)?

Comment: yes... I am unable to use them.. If u can provide me some references to learn how to use the CPAN modules that would be a great help for me...

Thanks...

Answer (score 3):

The [Verilog-Perl](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Verilog-Perl/) distribution on CPAN can be used to parse your Verilog code to create a list of signals.  If you have full control over the layout of your Verilog code, you don't need to use this module.  However, keep in  mind that parsing Verilog is not trivial.

Comment: Yes its not easy..... im doing parsing on combinational blocks which will convert into some boolean expression. can u provide me some references where i could learn how to use CPAN modules....? 

Thanks...

Comment: What do you mean by "use"?  If you mean "install", that could be as trivial as running the `cpan` command.  `perldoc cpan`

Comment: Worth noting: There must be something broken in how the author set up the meta files that facilitate indexing of Verilog-Perl.  `cpan Verilog-Perl` doesn't find it.  You can use pattern matching to find it though: `cpan /Verilog-Perl/`.  And it seems to prefer *nix environments.